# Content Loading is shown on Page before Preloader appears

Tags: javascript, html, css, preloader

Hello Guys I have an issue with the content loading of my webpage. I see the textfields and images laoding before the preloader sequence is starting.

This is my basic html structure

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Barcamp22</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script>
   $(window).on('load',function(){
    $('.load-wrapper').fadeOut(1000);
    $('.content').show();
    })
  </script>
  <div class="load-wrapper">
   <div class="loader"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   <div class="slider">
          <div class="sliderTrack">
            <div class="slider-item">
              <img src="./public/aula1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="slider-item">
              <img src="./public/big_session.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="slider-item">
             <img src="./public/blockchain_session.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="slider-item">
              <img src="./public/cake.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="slider-item">
              <img src="./public/chris.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="slider-item">
              <img src="./public/day2_start.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="slider-item">
              <img src="./public/holzkette_session.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="slider-item">
              <img src="./public/me.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="slider-item">
              <img src="./public/outside.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="slider-item">
              <img src="./public/robot.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="slider-item">
              <img src="./public/session1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="slider-item">
              <img src="./public/session_plan.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="slider-item">
              <img src="./public/session_plannings.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="slider-item">
              <img src="./public/sweet.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="slider-item">
              <img src="./public/VR.jpg">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <blockquote>
          <p>Das Barcamp 2022, eine Veranstaltung auf der gelernt, connected und gefeiert wurde</p>
        </blockquote>
    
        <section>
          <h2> Veranstalter</h2>
    
          <p>
            Eine Herzliche Begrüßung mit allerlei leckereien und Getränken, gefolgt von einer Vorstellungsrunde, die Christoph super umgesetzt hat. Es wurden Sessions geplant, in denen die Teilnehmer sich über aktuelle Themen der Holz- und Digitalbranche austauschen konnten. Jeder hatte dadurch die Chance nicht nur neues lernen zu können
             und Interessante Möglichkeiten zu Konzepten auszuarbeiten, sondern auch die Themen die einem selbst am wichtigsten sind mit einzubringen. In meinem Fall war das die Blockchain. Insgesamt wurde durch die Veranstalter eine Atmosphäre geschaffen, in der sich jeder beteiligen und man dadurch gemeinsam kreativ werden konnte.
          </p>
           ...
        </section>
  </div>
  <div>
    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

In my css file I used this line to hide the content

```
.content
{
 display: none;
}
```

I really can't figure out why I see the text and images without styling properties for like one or two seconds before the preloader is shown, would be very helpful if someone has an idea.

This is the loading flow of my page:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think your codes is not enough for others to understood the problem. For example I could not see any ```text and images``` in your codes. Put the part of codes that if you want to answer your **own question**, you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: what is your exact goal? do you want to show ```.content``` after ```.load-wrapper``` completely faded out? means after 1000 ms for example?

Comment: I have editet my question again to make it clear. The first two pictures are showing my problem. Before the preloading sequence is starting I see the textual content withput their css propertys for one second, then I see the pictures without styling for one second and then the loader sequence with fade-in and fade-out is starting. I want to remove the first two steps from the loading process of the page.

Comment: you could do lazy loading, make your html blank actually and fill it with an ajax call, this way you pre-loader has time to render. Not sure if thats what you want. The preloading can be done within same ajax call as a `beforeSend:` function within that Ajax call.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. While researching for ajax calls I was able to recognize the problem. Its because I use a static page and even with ajax calls, fixing this will be difficult. I will just go with the new next framework for a better rendering.

Answer (score 1):

I think these codes could help you solve the problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Barcamp22</title>
  <style>
    .content
    {
      display: none;
    }
    .loader {
      font-size: 50px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  $(window).on('load',function(){
    $('.load-wrapper').fadeOut(3000, function () {
      $('.content').show();
    });

  })
</script>
<div class="load-wrapper">
  <div class="loader">
    Loading...
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="sliderTrack">
      <div class="slider-item">
        <img src="./public/aula1.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-item">
        <img src="./public/big_session.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-item">
        <img src="./public/blockchain_session.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-item">
        <img src="./public/cake.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-item">
        <img src="./public/chris.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-item">
        <img src="./public/day2_start.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-item">
        <img src="./public/holzkette_session.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-item">
        <img src="./public/me.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-item">
        <img src="./public/outside.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-item">
        <img src="./public/robot.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-item">
        <img src="./public/session1.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-item">
        <img src="./public/session_plan.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-item">
        <img src="./public/session_plannings.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-item">
        <img src="./public/sweet.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="slider-item">
        <img src="./public/VR.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <blockquote>
    <p>Das Barcamp 2022, eine Veranstaltung auf der gelernt, connected und gefeiert wurde</p>
  </blockquote>

  <section>
    <h2> Veranstalter</h2>

    <p>
      Eine Herzliche Begrüßung mit allerlei leckereien und Getränken, gefolgt von einer Vorstellungsrunde, die Christoph super umgesetzt hat. Es wurden Sessions geplant, in denen die Teilnehmer sich über aktuelle Themen der Holz- und Digitalbranche austauschen konnten. Jeder hatte dadurch die Chance nicht nur neues lernen zu können
      und Interessante Möglichkeiten zu Konzepten auszuarbeiten, sondern auch die Themen die einem selbst am wichtigsten sind mit einzubringen. In meinem Fall war das die Blockchain. Insgesamt wurde durch die Veranstalter eine Atmosphäre geschaffen, in der sich jeder beteiligen und man dadurch gemeinsam kreativ werden konnte.
    </p>
    ...
  </section>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Because I don't have your styles, I could not say that it definitely makes your goal. The [fadeOut](https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) method have a second parameter that you can define a function in that. This function is called after the **fade-out** effect **completely** finished.

Comment: First thanks for your help. The problem is, even if declare the content as display: none and never fade it in, I see the content loading like in the first two pictures. I have to apologize for don't mention that this is a static page and I figured out that this is the problem. Anyway this already took me a lot of time and I don't go for static pages in the future, instead of fixing this problem for a static page,  I will migrate it to next13 because in this framework it should work.

Comment: @Felix Jost I think the reason of **content loading** is that you used ```$('.content').show()```. Although you set ```display: none``` for it, But that method shows it.

Comment: I also tried it with never showing the content, but the texts and images are still loading.